# Request-reply broker in ZeroMQ using one worker with asynchronous tasks

Tags: c#, zeromq

I want to implement a design similar to the **Request-Reply Broker** from the [ZeroMQ zguide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall) but instead of having multiple worker threads running ahead of time, I want to have one worker that receives all the requests, and spawns asynchronous operations (tasks) to handle them and send the responses.

What would be the proper combination of socket types to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this using the following combination of socket types:

**Request:**

> Client DEALER --> Server ROUTER --> Request handler (spawned)

1. Clients send requests via a DEALER socket on port
2. Server receives requests via a ROUTER socket on port
3. Server passes both the request and the client identity directly to request handlers when they are spawned

**Reply:**

> Client DEALER <-- Server ROUTER <-- Server DEALER <-- Request handler
>   DEALER

1. Request handler returns the reply to the Server via a `DEALER` socket on `inproc`
2. Server receives the reply from the request handler via a `DEALER` socket on `inproc`
3. Server sends the reply to the client via a `ROUTER` socket on a tcp port
4. Client receives the reply via a `DEALER` socket on a tcp port

I posted the example here:
https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/Python/asyncrrhandlers.py

Comment: this sounds perfect, do you have a c# implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to implement the [Load Balancing Message Broker](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#A-Load-Balancing-Message-Broker) with only one worker. This pattern is described in the Guide, that literally states:

"This broker does the following:

- Accepts connections from a set of clients.
- Accepts connections from a set of workers.
- Accepts requests from clients and holds these in a single queue.
- Sends these requests to workers using the load balancing pattern.
- Receives replies back from workers.
- Sends these replies back to the original requesting client.
  "

If you have only one worker all the requests are kept in the queue and processed in a FIFO fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there's only one publisher and one receiver at all times then - in that case Request/Recieve is the easiest one.  However moving to publish/subscribe pattern, and having multiple receivers, will allow you to scale horizontally if need be.

Comment: It needs to support multiple simultaneous requests. REQ/REP doesn't support that.

Comment: Which does?  You've got two pathways - marshaller (mapper, or whatever) to worker, and worker back to marshaller, correct?

Comment: Request path:
**(multiple clients)** -- requests --> **(service endpoint)** --> **async task workers**
....
Response path:
**(multiple clients)** <-- responses -- **(service endpoint)** <-- **async task workers**